# Confusion over それで+なら meaning

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

In [this video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=fKnI7ZLY4p0&t=1m46s), the characters are saying the lines they had in the game, only reworded, but they basically mean the same thing.

> やってみせる、それで自分が取り戻せるなら。

In the video game, there is a line of text:

> 自分自身を取り戻せるなら、やってみせるさ。

> "If it will make me myself again, I'll do whatever it takes."

Which I'll assume says just about the same thing as the video, just reworded. Both lines are spoken by the same character. But I've always been confused about the それで since all it says in the dictionaries for それで is

> 1. and; thereupon; because of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それで literally means "with this", and it does have various usages. Bit in this context, それで simply means "with/using this approach" or "in this way".  It means the same thing as その方法で or そのやり方で.

それで meaning "and" or "by the way" is a fixed set phrase, and that's why it's described in dictionaries. それで in your question is a simple combination of それ and で as the method/means marker.

Comment: What puzzled me was the なら on the end. I doesn't seem to fit to me. 自分自身を取り戻せるなら、やってみせるさ stands alone, but やってみせる、それで自分が取り戻せるなら seems like there's something left unsaid, or have I missed something?

Comment: @user3856370 It's [倒置](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%80%92%E7%BD%AE). But this shouldn't be hard to English speakers since English if-clauses can be placed at the end of a sentence.

Comment: If the それで weren't there then it would make sense to me. To borrow the OP's words: "やってみせる、自分が取り戻せるなら = I'll do whatever it takes, if it will make me myself again".  That's fine. But if I add in the それで I get "I'll do whatever it takes, **and with that if** it will make me myself again"., which doesn't make sense. What I actually want is "I'll do whatever it takes, and with that I will make me myself again". The それで and the なら don't seem to play nicely together. Or at least the "if" and the "and with that" don't play nicely together in English.

Comment: @user3856370 Where did that "and" come from? それで is a simple adverbial modifier here, and an adverb usually comes after the corresponding verb in English. The literal translation is simply "I will do it if I can regain myself with it" or "If I can regain myself with it, I will do it."

Comment: Sorry but this is still not making sense to me. Perhaps I'm failing to understand what the "it/this/that" in "with it/this/that" is. I had assumed it referred to the act of "doing whatever it takes". I can remove the 'and' from 'and with that' and split it into two sentences but it still makes no sense to me. Very confused here.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it: "I'll do it if, by means of doing it, I can regain myself.". I need to think about this a bit more, but more importantly I need to go to sleep. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: @user3856370 This それ is literally "it" and refers to some concrete plan suggested in the previous context (e.g. killing a dragon, diving into a waterfall, or anything). "If I can regain myself with that plan, I will put it in action."